# Is there a way to set apache/PHP/.htaccess to just return the error 404 without showing a page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-404

So I installed standard apache2 on linux ubuntu, but the default config will give the standard 404 page of apache2, while I'd like to just have an error, but no page returned.

I found some sort of workaround using the following in the apache2 config

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and then in 404.php:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found", true, 404);
```

But this still returns something, while I like the apache2 server to just stop there and don't do anything at all

Comment: What do you think it returns? It should only return the headers unless you are doing something else in the `404.php` file, which is pretty much an empty response. You could always add an `exit()` after the `header()` call to force PHP to stop processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your ErrorDocument to show your custom error response without loading a new page .

The following code will show the  custom text "A 404 error occurred" in a new window if you request something that doesn't exist on your server.

```
ErrorDocument 404 "A 404 error occurred!"
```

You can also use HTML tags to format the error text

```
 ErrorDocument 404 "<h2>A 404 error occurred!</h2>"
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that, but I really needed to not have any output and just get the error, thought there was a better way...

Thank you anyway!